# MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, plugins

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo_firebase/auth/authscreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:todo_firebase/screens/home.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  //initilization of Firebase app

  // other Firebase service initialization

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, usersnapshot) {
          if (usersnapshot.hasData) {
            return Home();
          } else {
            return AuthScreen();
          }
        },
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light, primaryColor: Colors.blue),
      // ignore: dead_code
    );
  }
}
```

This is my main.dart code.
I get the following output at 'await Firebase.initializeApp()':
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core))

I'm trying to make a daily task app but whenever I execute it using VSCode, it builds a Windows Application that appears blank. I've written the whole code in the different sections of lib (authentication and homepage), main.dart, and pubspec.yaml but it is not executing. Kindly provide the method to fix the error, and make my app work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had this issue this morning.. What a problem it was! Took me a few hours to figure out. Everything is working now though!

What did I do? I tried cleaning my project out, deleted ios file and ran `flutter create .` a few times with no luck... Pulled my hair out!

What fixed it?

- update your gems
- delete ios file for the 5th time (LOL)
- delete "derived data" in xcode and clean build folder in xcode

run `flutter clean` inside your project and then run `flutter pub cache repair`

Then you need to manually update your pubspec.yaml  with the latest version of firebase core, etc. Yes make sure you delete lock file first then manually update the dependencies.  **DO NOT run** `flutter pub upgrade`.  Won't work.. Just manually add them in :(

**This is what I manually added into my pubspec.yaml:**

```
cloud_firestore: ^3.2.1
firebase_core: ^1.19.1
firebase_storage: ^10.3.1
firebase_auth: ^3.4.1
firebase_messaging: ^11.4.4
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up trying everything including disabling `minify`, however nothing worked for me. After comparing to another project I found out that apparently `flutter pub` was being weird and was using `1.x.x` as the version constraint(even though I was adding the dependency through `flutter pub add`).

Changing the dependency in `pubspec.yaml` to `2.x.x` worked:

```yaml
dependencies:
    ....
    firebase_core: ^2.7.1
```

Please ensure that you are using the correct version from: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core.

You can also do the same for other firebase plugin packages if you are facing a similar issue with them.

Answer (score 1):

First of check all your app must not be running on any device If running then stop it and then
Fire  these command into terminal
`Flutter clean`
Then
`Flutter pub get`

Then run your project

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the latest firebase_core version 1.19.0
Try to use the previous version:

```
firebase_core: ^1.18.0
```

At least this solved the problem for me.